# Can a class instance return tuple without using attribute?

Tags: python, vector, magic-methods

I've got a small problem which in itself isn't a big deal but is bugging me none the less. Consider the code below.

```
import pygame

class vector:
    def __init__(s, x, y):
        s.x = int(x)
        s.y = int(y)
        s.t = (s.x, s.y)

    def __add__(s, n):
        return vector(s.x + n[0], s.y + n[1])

size = vector(10, 10)

pygame.Surface((size + (5, 5)).t)
```

When passing vector as a parameter to pygame.Surface I have to use the 't' attribute to access the tuple stored in 'size'.

Is there a way to have it simply like this?

```
pygame.Surface(size + (5, 5))
```

Is there a magic method that returns a value if no attribute or method is referenced?

In pygame you can define a vector like this, *v = pygame.math.vector2(10, 10)* and then pass that vector to a surfaces blit function like this, *someSurface.blit(sprite, v)* and there's no need to reference a method or attribute to get the value so it does seem possible, though I guess it's perfectly plausible that the blit function can handle a vector2 as an argument?

Thank you for you time.

Comment: As a side note: everyone respects the convention of using `self`, not `s`. Don't make your code more difficult to read for us...

Comment: more difficult?

Comment: Generally, everytime it breaks well respected conventions, reading code is less easy and fluid. Conventions in Python are very well respected. See the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) official style guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `__len__` and `__getitem__`:

```py
class vector:
    def __init__(s, x, y):
        s.x = int(x)
        s.y = int(y)
        s.t = (s.x, s.y)

    def __add__(s, n):
        return vector(s.x + n[0], s.y + n[1])

    def __len__(s):
        return 2
   
    def __getitem__(s, i):
        return [s.x, s.y][i]
```

Comment: This works thank you. That'll make my code a bit tidier :)